# Cyrus murder and IMAP backend cluster on failover

Tags: imap, cyrus

I have one cyrus murder (aggregator) master and a IMAP backend cluster on failover consisting of 2 nodes (**backend1** and **backend2**).

I use corosync/pacemaker to set :

- a virtual IP
- start and stop the cyrus-imapd service

for the backend IMAP cluster.

I use too drbd to synchronize the /var/lib/imap and the /var/spool/imap between my 2 IMAP backends.

For example, the cyrus-imapd service runs on the **backend1**. When **userA** creates folders and subfolders in their INBOX, the **backend1** requets the aggregator with the mupdate protocole. It replied positively and on the aggregator's mailboxes.db we have the folders plus the **backend's name** where the folder is stored.

Even if the **backend1** stops, the **backend2** takes over. When **userA** create folder, cyrus-imapd requests from the aggregator if it can create the folder. The aggregator replied negatively because the aggregator knows that the **userA**'s mailbox is managed by the **backend1**. It doesn't know that **backend1** and **backend2** are the "same". So it ordered the **backend2** to delete the mailbox. But as their datas are replicated, so the maibox disappears on **backend1**.

So my question is the following :
Is there an option, in the imapd.conf or something else that allows my 2 backend's IMAP appear with the same name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to set the same 'servername' option on both machines in imapd.conf.

{ "servername", NULL, STRING }
/* This is the hostname visible in the greeting messages of the POP,
   IMAP and LMTP daemons. If it is unset, then the result returned
   from gethostname(2) is used. */

That's not all it does though - it's also used by murder to identify the server.

Comment: Okay I didn't think I could use the servername option because there is no indication in the definition of this option that it is used in the **MUPDATE**protocol . So I'm going to test it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've updated the docs in git to say this: This is the hostname visible in the greeting messages of the POP,
   IMAP and LMTP daemons. If it is unset, then the result returned
   from gethostname(2) is used.  This is also the value used by murder 
   clusters to identify the host name.  It should be resolvable by 
   DNS to the correct host, and unique within an active cluster.  If 
   you are using low level replication (e.g. drbd) then it should be 
   the same on each copy and the DNS name should also be moved to
   the new master on failover.